# zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file when using "openpyxl" engine

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, boto3, python-zipfile

I have created a script which dumps the excel sheets stored in S3 into my local postgres database. I've used pandas read_excel and ExcelFile method to read the excel sheets.
Code for the same can be found here.

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import io
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import xlrd

os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"] = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"
os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"] = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

obj = s3.get_object(Bucket='bucket-name', Key='file.xlsx')
data = pd.ExcelFile(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()))
print(data.sheet_names)
a = len(data.sheet_names)

engine1 = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres')
for i in range(a):
    df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()),sheet_name=data.sheet_names[i], engine='openpyxl')
    df.to_sql("test"+str(i), engine1, index=False)
```

Basically, code parses the S3 bucket and runs in a loop. For each sheet, it creates a table
and dumps the data from sheet in that table.

Where I'm having trouble is, when I run this code, I get this error.

```
df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()),sheet_name=data.sheet_names[i-1], engine='openpyxl')
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

This is coming after I added 'openpyxl' engine in read_excel method. When I remove the engine, I get this error.

```
raise ValueError(
ValueError: Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually.
```

Please note that I can print the connection to database, so there is no problem in connectivity, and I'm using latest version of python and pandas. Also, I can get all the sheet_names in the excel file so I'm able to reach to that file as well.

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the `obj` twice, fully:

1. `data = pd.ExcelFile(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()))`
2. `pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(obj['Body'].read()), ...)`

Your object can only be `.read()` once, second read produce nothing, an empty `b""`.

In order to avoid re-reading the S3 stream many times, you could store it once in a BytesIO, and rewind that BytesIO with `seek`.

```py
buf = io.BytesIO(obj["Body"].read())

pd.ExcelFile(buf)

buf.seek(0)

pd.read_excel(buf, ...)

# repeat
```

Comment: I can remove it, obj['Body'].read(),  like this. But can you tell me how to close the first obj after reading it?   PS: Even after removing BytesIO, I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Well, you load the content of object twice, which is unnecessary and time consuming, you must be able to find a way to load it only once, and pass its data around.

Comment: Actually it's not twice, it loads the content as many times the loop runs :_). I understand now all the other runs are useless.

Comment: @Suraj221b See my edit, you can do something like this, file is read once from S3 and kept in memory while you iterate over the sheets.

Comment: Yes, Thank you for the answer. I stored the data after my first read and simply passed the data in the next read_excel. :)